# Sending an image over the network in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am having a problem sending a .PNG image over a network. I have multiple clients connected to a single server. A client chooses the user to whom she would like to send the image to. Here is the code snippet on client side.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(source));
ImageIO.write(img, "png", spGUI.sdtGUI.output);
```

where spGUI.sdtGUI.output is an output stream wrapped around the output stream of the socket.

I am getting an exception that it cannot write the PNG file.

PS:I don't know how to include the stack trace in the post.

Comment: put the code for creation of spGUI.sdtGUI.output and list the stack trace (if using command line-   java file.class > output.txt)

Comment: Actually, since the stack trace is written to standard error output by default, you'll need `java … 2>output.txt`.  At least in Bash-like shells.  But no matter what terminal emulator or IDE you are using, you should be able to somehow select the output with the mouse and copy & paste it if everything else fails.